# Trying to make a program that calculates Triangle area, i want to use it with Math.Round but dont know where to place it correclty

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double h = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double plosht = (a * h) / 2;
        double area = plosht ;
        Math.Round(plosht, 2);    
        Console.WriteLine(plosht);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the Math.Round method but i have no idea where to put it

Answer (score 5):

Rather than rounding the number before displaying it, you should normally round it when turning it into a string:

```
Console.WriteLine(plosht.ToString("f2"));
```

The reason is that you commonly want to retain full precision in your numbers in case you want to do further calculation with them after displaying interim results. The rounding is more to do with how you want to show it to the user than how you want to store it in a `double` or other floating point type.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have `polsht` rounded to 2 digits use this:

```
plosht = Math.Round(plosht, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Round` is a method that returns a value, it doesn't modify the argument that you pass it.  Try this:

```
double rounded = Math.Round(plosht, 2);
Console.WriteLine(rounded);
```

That being said, I think Matthew Watson's answer is the way to go.